Feynman trajectories of a photon from entangled pair
In a pair of Entangled photons does any of the two photons has the Feynman trajectories of the other one? Must the possible trajectories of photon 2 be taken in the Feynman's path integral for the amplitude of photon 1 or one must take only the trajectories which are possible for photon 1?
